# Wordpress Custom pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to load all my custom pages on front-page by using the function get_template_part(); but whenever I save my code the page loads everything on front-page but is keeps on looping the content over and over and over again on the site.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/header'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-about'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-services'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-portfolio'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-contact'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

I'm also going to upload it to github https://github.com/brandonpowell/Test-Wordpress-Site/tree/master/danielschriersite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are calling the header in multiples times tries to remove each of the templates

[image]

also you call in frontpage template

try using wordpress pages templates

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/header'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/page-about'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/page-services'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/page-portfolio'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/page-contact'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and the back you change the page template attr from the admin dashboard

[image]

you can also use is_front_page() function

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ) { ?>

       <?php get_template_part('templates/header'); ?>
       <?php get_template_part('templates/page-about'); ?>
       <?php get_template_part('templates/page-services'); ?>
       <?php get_template_part('templates/page-portfolio'); ?>
       <?php get_template_part('templates/page-contact'); ?>
       <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @HermanAndresFigeroa Yes I have change the template to front page the works what trying to say here that when him on front-page not loading all the content just constantly repeating itself. https://gyazo.com/b51d13f7ac66cc702d2147925f19b0a7 and I have looked at that wordpress link already lot of time

Comment: @HermanAndresFigeroa Yes him Calling in every template in Backend of wordpress. Do you have a Skype add brandonpdesigns so I can explain this little better to you

Comment: Many times include the Templates and content of As such no esta repeating the the_content () ? http://i.imgur.com/NDQbNDx.png

Comment: tries only leave an invocation of the template, get_template_part () to check if the content keeps repeating itself

Comment: @HermanAndresFigeroa What do you mean about leave invocation of the template him still learn development wordpress.